# Single page app (SPA) cache config for nginx

Tags: nginx, single-page-application

I have a small single page app running on a server, every time I make changes to it, some users report errors on their browsers. Those errors disappear after clearing history, meaning that parts of the SPA got cached. I added the no-cache tag on the main SPA page.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  client_max_body_size 25M;
  server_name [COMMENTED_OUT];
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access_log.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error_log.log;
  server_tokens off;
  location / {
    try_files $uri /static/index.html;
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
  }
  location /static/ {
    autoindex off;
    alias /static/;
  }
}
```

Is there anything that I'm doing wrong on this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the expiration selectively:

```
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
  default                     off;
  text/html                   epoch;
  text/css                    1d;    # based on mime type
  application/javascript      1d;
  ~image/                     max;   # based on path
}
```

Declare this on top of your site config, outside the server directive. Then add this inside the server config:

```
server {
   ...
   expires $expires;
   ...
}
```

Comment: thanks, currently getting - nginx: [emerg] invalid number of the map parameters in /etc/nginx/conf.d/dev.conf:5

Comment: Have you deleted comments?

Comment: I did now, my bad. Will let it run for a bit and see if this works. Thank you.

Comment: Seems to have worked, thanks